# multiple tinymces in colorbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce, colorbox

I'm writing an inline CMS where content is edited by admins by hitting 'edit' buttons on the front end.

I need web forms containing multiple tinymces to open in a lightbox and need an elegant solution. I have the web forms working at their own urls (for non js users), and am loading these in with ajax into a colorbox lightbox. This is what I have so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".ajax").colorbox({
        onComplete : function(){ tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, "mytextarea"); },
        onClosed   : function(){ tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, "mytextarea");}
    });
});
...
<a class='ajax' href="/mywebformurl #mywebform">Edit</a>
```

I have three problems:

1. This only works for text areas with the id `mytextarea`. I want it to work with all text areas with the class `.tiny_mce` (as per my tinymce config which has `mode : "specific_textareas", editor_selector : "tiny_mce"`).
2. I don't want to load tinymce on the host page, only when the lightbox is opened.
3. How can I remove the `#mywebform` addition to the href, but still get it to load only the webform, and not the entire page at /mywebformurl?

Essentially, I'd like the ajax loaded content to be independent, and work as it does when I visit the mywebform url directly (making it's own js includes etc). I am considering an iFrame rather than ajax, but have always worked on the assumption that iframes should be avoided at all costs.